# Call a function within another Software

Tags: c, nxp-microcontroller

I have two softwares within the µC, firmware and application.
from application I want to call Calculate_Crc which is compiled in firmware.
when I perform directly the call the execution is not performed succuffly, the code jumps to other locations.
in that function, I have global data and one subfuntion.

What is the safest manner to call this function?

I'm using Diab Compiler & C langage.

```
            const unsigned long  g_poly_Cst;
            unsigned long  Calculate_Crc32( const void *Src, unsigned char Size, unsigned long Crc, const void *Poly)
            { 
              unsigned long        crc      = ( unsigned long)(crcval); 
              unsigned char      areaSize = Size;             
              g_poly_Cst = *((const unsigned char *)Poly);
              const unsigned char  *data = (*((unsigned char **)&Src_Ptr));          
              unsigned char         bitSize;                                                                  
              while (areaSize != 0)               
                {                                 
                crc ^= ((unsigned long)(*(data++)) << (((sizeof(unsigned long) -1)*8) *((1 << 1)/2)) ); 
                bitSize = 8+1;                    
                while (--bitSize != 0)            
                  {                               
                  if ( (crc & ((unsigned long)((unsigned long)(3 << ((sizeof(unsigned long)*4)-1) ) shift (sizeof(unsigned long)*4))) ) !=0) 
                     crc = (unsigned long)((crc << 1) ^ g_poly_Cst);
                  else                            
                    crc = (unsigned long)(crc << 1);
                  }                               
                areaSize--;                       
                }                     
              }

                Notify_UpperLayer(DONE);                    
                return Crc;                                                               
            }
```

Comment: Software interrupt?  That's how it's usually done.

Comment: Please provide more information. Does the firmware has a library provided for your application? Are both, firmware and application written in C? How do you perform the call directly?

Comment: both of them are written in C. It has no library provided for the application. Actually, it is a function that calculates CRC. The firmware can use it internally to calculate the integrity of the application then the application can use it to calculate a CRC for a given area. The current access is by pointer which is initialized by the address of this function. the address is provided by the firmware.

Comment: @StackOver hmm, if you call it directly, and the code jumps to other locations (in which code?), then your address may be wrong ... as you state it jumps to other locations.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName, How can I avoid that? could you please provide me the different steps to perform.

Comment: @StackOver Can you provide us with the details ... how does the function definion look in your firmware ... and how do you call it in your application, and where does it jump. Maybe than someone could help.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName, the description is updated. Is it clear now?

Comment: This code looks mighty dangerous. Be very afraid of someone writing `(1 << 1)/2` instead of `1`... then multiply something with `1`... This code is for the IOCCC? The safest would be to not call it at all. I hope all those "globals" are `static const`. And I bet there's a flood of implicit integer promotion bugs lurking in there. Happy debugging...

Comment: I don't understand it ... you give the function a parameter "unsigned long Crc" and at the end return this same value? Shouldn't you return small crc instead?

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName, the input parameter CRC is the initial value,it has sense when we want to caluclate a CRC for noncontiguous blocks. the function  returns the new calculated CRC.

Comment: @Lundin, why this algorithm is not safe?what's the difference between globals and static const in that case?

Comment: @StackOver It is dangerous because the person who wrote it evidently had no clue what they were doing. The difference between globals and local file scope constant is spaghetti versus private encapsulation.